# Error with my python code

Tags: python

I am new to python with great desire to learn the language. However, right now i need someone help with a code i am currently working on which keep flagging this error : 
Oops, try again. get_average(alice) returned None instead of the expected 91.15

This is the question with my solution below also:
Write a function called get_average that takes a student dictionary (like lloyd, alice, or tyler) as input and returns his/her weighted average.

Define a function called get_average that takes one argument called student.
Make a variable homework that stores the average() of student["homework"].
Repeat step 2 for "quizzes" and "tests".
Multiply the 3 averages by their weights and return the sum of those three. Homework is 10%, quizzes are 30% and tests are 60%.

MY SOLUTION:

```
lloyd = {
"name": "Lloyd",
"homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
"quizzes": 88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
"tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
"name": "Alice",
"homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
"quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
"tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = { 
"name": "Tyler",
 "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
"quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
"tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}

# Add your function below!
def average(numbers):
    total = sum(numbers)
    total = float(total)
    result = total/len(numbers)
    return result

def get_average(student):
    homework = average(student["homework"])
    quizzes = average(student["quizzes"])
    tests = average(student["tests"])
    Av = (0.1 * homework) + (0.6 * tests) +(0.3 * quizzes)
    print Av
```

Comment: `get_average` needs to `return Av`

Comment: This code works apart from the SyntaxError in line 4:  
"quizzes": 88.0, 40.0, 94.0],  
Also you should probably return Av, and print it from where the function was called

Comment: replace in `get_average` "print Av" to "return Av". And you have syntax error in `lloyd ` `dict` , check the `quizzes ` values.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can also try this:

```
import numpy as np
def weighted_average(d):
 """Returns weighted average of values corresponding to keys homework, 
    tests & quizzes of a dictionary d"""

    # bind dict keys to variables homework, test, quiz
    homework, test, quiz = [d["homework"]], [d["tests"]], [d["quizzes"]]
    # calculate average through np.mean() and Return the value
    return "Average: {}".format((0.1 * np.mean(homework)) + (0.6 * np.mean(test)) + (0.3 * np.mean(quiz)))    

d = lloyd = {"name": "Lloyd","homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],"quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],"tests": [75.0, 90.0]}
averages(d)

>>>'Average: 80.55'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code, fixed the missing opening bracket at line 4 (looyd quizzes) and it's working well.

```
    lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
    }
    alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
    }
    tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
     "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
    }

    # Add your function below!
    def average(numbers):
        total = sum(numbers)
        total = float(total)
        result = total/len(numbers)
        return result

    def get_average(student):
        homework = average(student["homework"])
        quizzes = average(student["quizzes"])
        tests = average(student["tests"])
        Av = (0.1 * homework) + (0.6 * tests) +(0.3 * quizzes)
        print Av

    get_average(alice)
```

This code is printing `91.15` on my python 2.7

Comment: Great! great!! great!!! @ Tifa. It works now. Guess i just have to be more watchful.